# What is the difference between these coordinate systems for New Brunswick

Tags: coordinate-system, import, canada, civil3d

AutoCAD Civil 3D has two coordinate reference systems that I've identified for use in New Brunswick, Canada: CANST-NB83-CSRS and CANST-NB-ATS

How do they differ?

Comment: Thank you for editing and making my question more clear!

Comment: ATS stands for ATS 1977, so it's the older geographic coordinate reference system (aka datum). CSRS is NAD 1983 Canadian Spatial Reference System, so much newer. Choice depends on what data you have, because you'll have to convert one to the other if you have both.